# my jwt token does not expire after 60 seconds

Tags: jwt, token, bearer-token

```cs
public string CreateToken(string username)
{
    var claims = new ClaimsIdentity();
    claims.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username));
    var tokennDescription = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
    {
        Subject = claims,
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(60),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(this.secret), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var createdToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokennDescription);
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(createdToken);
}
```

I read that using utc hour causes conflict, I added ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero and it worked but I read that in practice it is not good to use it, any practical solution?

I need the token to expire after 60 seconds, regardless of the time zone you are in and the time of your device.

Comment: *I read that using utc hour causes conflict,* - where did you read it and what conflict should it cause? JWT generally uses UTC-based timestamps to be independent from timezones.

Comment: @jps They said that it was an old function and that instant is the new function of Java 8

Comment: @JorgeMantilla is this Java? To me it looks like C# code

Comment: @pochopsp is C#